# Careless mistakes in formulas shouldn't be treated the same as non-mainstream physics

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen, vote-to-close

In this question,

*[What is the Schrödinger equation in position velocity space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658360/)*

I originally made a careless mistake when writing the Schrödinger equation in velocity space, as I had originally put a $m^3$ in the denominator of part of the equation instead of putting $m$ in the numerator, which I have since corrected.

Now the way I made this mistake is that I thought about how $\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{p}}{m}$ and from getting the velocity and momentum mixed up, changed $\vec{p}^2$ to $\frac{v^2}{m^2}$ instead of $\vec{v}^2m$ and failed to see that I had implicitly assumed $\vec{p}=\frac{\vec{v}}{m}$ until I edited my question to show how I derived the Schrödinger equation in velocity space and noticed my mistake.  The reason I didn't notice when someone commented on my question that $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$ is because I assumed that he/she wasn't thinking about the form $\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{p}}{m}$.

I think in general if a wrong equation can be explained by a careless mistake such as mixing up $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{p}$ in $\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{p}}{m}$, or forgetting a term in an equation, when a question and the equations in it are long, it should be considered a sign of a careless mistake rather than asking from the perspective of non-mainstream physics.

Comment: Obvious typos can be corrected, but that can be tricky when the typo is in an equation, because it can be hard to tell if it *is* a mere typo or an actual error.

Answer (score 14):

I did not vote to close but I do not see a relation between the two comments pointing at the maths mistake and the closing vote. That is, I don't think the typo is what led them to close the question as 'non-mainstream'.

I actually don't know why someone would treat this question as non-mainstream as I personally find it makes sense and fits within the current, established formulation of QM.

Some users (including me) have voted to reopen the question, and it has now been re-opened. I have deleted the comments pointing out the mistake just not to derail the focus.

Comment: Yeah I can’t imagine that typos are enough to close a question unless the typo is *major* and makes everything non-sensical.

Comment: Already getting to work reopening questions and deleting comments, I see :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist, it's SuperDuperCiocia now!